# Can I tell render *not* to use layout?

Tags: camping

If I want to have a special view, say for embedding in an `iframe`, can I pass something to the `render` method to have it avoid wrapping my view with the layout, or use a specific layout to do the wrapping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure:

```
render :foobar, :layout => false
```

Comment: Did this change in a recent version? I tried this yesterday and it didn't. Updated to 2.1.532 and it does.